# TypeScript: Specify a return value as well defined

Tags: typescript, undefined

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html every "type" is implicitly "type | undefined | null". Meaning I can assign undefined or null to every variable unless you enforce "--strictNullChecks". Enforcing strictNullChecks would be great, but that´s not my decision so assume that this no option for now.

So instead of always checking for an undefined variable of an object i was wondering if you could write a function that takes in an object that might has undefined or null properties and returns an object that is "well defined". Here is an example of what i mean:

```
function WellDefineObject(object: SomeObjectType): SomeObjectType(*but well defined*){
    const wellDefinedObject = {
        id: (object.id == undefined || object.id == null) ? "" : object.id
    }
    return wellDefinedObject;
}
```

So is there a solution to my problem apart from enabling strictNullChecks?

Comment: Having `strictNullChecks` off is living on the wild side!  I never have it off so I have to look up how it works.  You might find some helpful utility types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Based on my current understanding, I honestly think that this is not possible when `strictNullChecks` is off.  You could return a type that does not include `null`, but that flag means you can assign `null` or `undefined` to anything, so your returned non-null version can still have `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the utility types. When using NonNullable<SomeObjectType> I still get the same compiler errors. I guess enabling strictNullChecks is the only option.

Comment: Have you tried with the [`Required<T>` (Typescipt Handbook)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) utility type?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not what you want:

```
type  SomeObjectType = {
   id?: string 
} 

function WellDefineObject(object: SomeObjectType): SomeObjectType{
    const wellDefinedObject = {
        id: (object.id == undefined || object.id == null) ? "" : object.id
    }
    return wellDefinedObject;
}
```

But how about it? :

```
type  SomeObjectType = {
   id: string 
} 

function WellDefineObject(object: {id? : SomeObjectType['id']}): SomeObjectType{
    const wellDefinedObject = {
        id: (object.id == undefined || object.id == null) ? "" : object.id
    }
    return wellDefinedObject;
}
```

In both ways:

```
console.log(WellDefineObject({}))
//[LOG]: {
//  "id": ""
//} 

console.log(WellDefineObject({id: "123"})) // only string fits
//[LOG]: {
//  "id": "123"  
//}
```

And at the end you can use generic:

```
type  SomeObjectType = {
   id: string 
} 

type NotWellDefined<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}

function WellDefineObject(object: NotWellDefined<SomeObjectType>): SomeObjectType{
    const wellDefinedObject = {
        id: (object.id == undefined || object.id == null) ? "" : object.id
    }
    return wellDefinedObject;
}
```